# Transform Scala case variable before if guard

Tags: scala

I'm using a Scala case statement as follows:

```
users.collect {
   case SomeClass(_, id, _, latestVersion, time) 
      if latestVersion.getOrElse("null") == someVariable || // etc. => 
         // bunch of stuff here
}
```

`latestVariable` is an `Option` and is used frequently inside the `if` and as part of the code nested inside it.

Is there a way I can transform the `Option[String]` latest version into a plain String of either `"null"` or the inner value before going into the `if` statement? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but I also don't understand why you'd need it. After that initial `if` test you'll know that `someVariable` is the same as the inner value of `latestVersion` so just use it instead.

Comment: @jwvh - not totally sure of that, since if there are other conditions allowing us to go inside the initial if test, the condition might not necessarily be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpertation of `None` as `"null"` string looks a bit disturbing. But otherwise I would usually write an extractor for a situation like this.

```
object VersionExtractor {
  /** I know it looks kinda funny but it does exactly what the op asked for. */
  def unnaply(in: Option[String]): Option[String] = in orElse Some("null")
}
```

You can use it like

```
case SomeClass(_, id, _, VersionExtractor(latestVersion), time) ...
```

where latestVersion now is a `String` that is either `"null"` or the content of the original `Option`.

However, in Scala, imho, this could be considered a maltreatment of both the `Option` and `Extractor`.

I think a better approach would be to write an extractor for the whole case, somewhere along the lines of

```
object MyExtractor {
  def unapply(input: SomeClass): Option[(<type of id>, String, <type of time>)] = {
    input.latestVersion match {
        // And now partially in pseudo code:
      case Some(version) /* if (input matches some criteria) */ => 
        Some((input.id, version, input.time))
      case _ => 
        None
    }
  }
}
```

If done right, your collect should then look like:

```
users.collect {
   case MyExtractor(id, latestVersion /*: String */, time) => 
         // bunch of stuff here
}
```

Comment: 'The interpertation of None as "null" string looks a bit disturbing.'  Agreed. Using null is a code smell in Scala.

Comment: I agree - unfortunately, I can't really change the string coming in and it can be a "null" string which we are comparing with

Answer (score 0):

You can do the test you want more easily by using pattern matching inside your case statement, as follows:

```
users.collect {
  case SomeClass(_, id, _, Some(someVariable), time) =>
     // bunch of stuff here
}
```

This tests that the `Option` is present and its value is equal to `someVariable`.